# Calculating sum until the indexPath.row instead of total using tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I had a question about calculation functions and I cant seem to understand the logic behind it yet as I just started to do coding in iOS about 3 months ago.

Here's a screenshot in the link and please take a look at it. 
[image: image here]

I would like to achieve results as explained Below

Expected Results : there will be more than 10000 cell of rows eventually, so my sum Cell will required to calculate based on the first index of the data instead of cell, I tried enumerated, mapping, for in loops but to no success
.

**PLEASE PROVIDE CODE ALONG WITH YOUR EXPLANATION SO I CAN UNDERSTAND AS I AM NOT AN EXPERIENCED CODER**

Example

`UIVIEW`

`TotalBalance = $ 28.00 << Achieve by updateTotal()`

`TableView`

1. TransactionType : $ 10.00 ($10.00) < this will sum cell 1 only as it is the first cell
2. TransactionType : $ 5.00  ($15.00) < this will sum cell 1 - 2 only
3. TransactionType : $ 3.00  ($18.00) < this will sum cell 1 - 3 only
4. TransactionType : $ 10.00 ($28.00) < this will sum cell 1 -  4 only

```
class Account: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var balance : Double = 0

    var ofTransaction = List<Transaction>()

}

class Transaction: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var amount : Double = 0

    var parentAccount = LinkingObjects(fromType: Account.self, property: "ofTransaction")

}

class AccountCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sum: UILabel!

}
```

```
    func updateTotal() {
        let total = getTransactions
            .map { $0.amount }
            .reduce(0, +)

        let totalFormatter = NumberFormatter()

        totallabel.text = totalFormatter.string(for: total)!
    }
```

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       account = realm.objects(Account.self)
       getTransactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self)

   }
 // MARK: - Table view data source
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AccountCell

       if let transCell = getTransactions?[indexPath.row] {
           cell.name.text = transCell.name
           cell.amount.text = "\(transCell.amount)"


           ///Wrong Logic : This logic updates the Sum to Total !
           let sumCell = getTransactions
               .map { $0.amount }
               .reduce(0, +)

           cell.sum.text = "\(sumCell)"

       }
       return cell
   }
```

Comment: It looks incorrect that you load the objects in `tableView:cellForRowAt`, this is something you should do only once when the table view is first shown like in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Im sorry about that, the getTransaction is actually in viewDidLoad

Comment: Then I think you should fix the code in the question because it will confuse people. Regarding only calculation the sum for part of the array you can do something like `array(indexPath.row).reduce(0, +)` or `array[0..<indexPath.row].reduce(0, +)`

Comment: alright. I had edited. thank you for the code and sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AccountCell

    if let transCell = getTransactions?[indexPath.row] {
        cell.name.text = transCell.name
        cell.amount.text = "\(transCell.amount)"

        //Correct calculation in Loops
        var sumUp = 0.0
        for (index,trans) in getTransactions.enumerated() {
            if (index == indexPath.row) { break }
            sumUp += trans.amount
            cell.sum.text = "\(sumUp)"

        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the code, I had tried your code and it's working as what I expected. However, row 0 will stay as ```UILabel``` and calculation will start from row 1

this is the print result which show the correct information as required
```index: 0, amount: 1, sumUp: 1```
```index: 1, amount: 3, sumUp: 4```
```index: 2, amount: 1, sumUp: 5```

in tableView.
```row: 0, amount: 1, sumUp: Label```
```row: 1, amount: 3, sumUp: 1```
```row: 2, amount: 1, sumUp: 4```

Comment: Also, I encountered another issue, which when I filter out the transactions in the cell, the tableview only calculate the listed Row, where my results are to based on the all cells, is mapping required if I want to calculate all even with filters?

Comment: [Here the screenshot of the issue I had](https://ibb.co/GHSsxG4)

Comment: It looks like you are picking only two transaction. While filtering, use getTransactions everytime. Don't update getTransactions. Would be helpful if you can share code snippet of filtering. Thanks.

Comment: I did not use any filtering for getTransactions yet as this code is based on my testing of functions to solve the issue by creating another xcworkspace. I put your code on main apps to test run only to realise it will calculate base on filtered Rows only.

Comment: I changed the indexPath.row by adding 1 and it worked as expected now, however, I dont understand why the indexPath.row required +1 ,is there any explanation in this ? the code now is `if (index == indexPath.row + 1) { break }`